# What is the man who controls or monitors student behavior in a high or secondary school called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In primary or secondary or high school in some countries, there is a man who patrols the school to make sure students behave well.

For example, he will send students in the principal's office if he sees them fight, damage school's property, spit, litter, swear etc.

Is that called "**the school superintendent**"?

**What is the man who controls or monitors student behavior in a high or secondary school called?**

Comment: _The principal's office_.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a generally accepted English-language term for this, because this is very culturally specific.  My high school did not have any such person.  *Superintendent* is not correct, because in American English that word means an administrator of the school district.

Comment: In most UK schools, the teachers or other school staff share this duty. There is no separate 'discipline cop' role.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly as described, this is not a role that is found in UK schools, and as such there is no term for it.

There are positions for "Behaviour support teaching assistant",  "Learning and Behaviour mentor" "Emotional and behavioural support practitioner" or even more euphemistically "Community engagement Officer".  All these roles are about engaging with young people who are misbehaving. A teacher may have special responsibility for leading the behaviour management at the school, but that person would still be primarily a teacher.

More generally, a school counsellor is a role that is about improving young people's mental health, and therefore their behaviour. But I would not expect a counsellor, nor a behaviour support teaching assistant to be patrolling the corridors.

The point is that it is *teachers* who are responsible for behaviour management in UK schools. Teachers will apply sanctions for fighting, vandalism, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Canada and the United States, it's a **[Hall Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_monitor)**.

This term more often refers to a *student* who has been assigned the duty of reporting bad behaviour in the hallways, but it can also apply to an adult staff member.